# Show link to iBook Store if one apple device

Tags: iphone, ios, ibooks

I am doing a site for an author who is releasing a book soon, and one of the stores the book will be on is the iBook store.

Since you cant view the store from anything but iTunes, is there a way I can generate a link if only on an apple device?

Answer (score 0):

If the user has iBooks installed on their device, the iBookstore link should navigate the user to the iBookstore book link. Just try using the iBookstore link for the book you'd like to navigate them to.

Comment: Right, but wouldn't that be kind of redundant for someone who doesn't have iBooks?

Also, I do not have iTunes or iBooks, nor do I have an apple device. How do I find a link to the book?

The book is TAMPA, by Alissa Nutting FYI